# Java: Finding region of Polygon A not intersected by Polygon B

Tags: java, geometry, polygon, intersection

I'm trying to create a Java method that receives two polygons as parameters and returns a third polygon that represents the portion of Polygon A that is not intersected by Polygon B. Here's a visual.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSAEH.png

Polygon A is the black polygon, Polygon B is the green polygon intersecting Polygon A, and the return Polygon is the blue shaded region within Polygon A.

Answer (score 1):

You need algorithms or library for boolean operations on polygons. Your example shows concave polygon, so you can use [Vatti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vatti_clipping_algorithm)  or [Greiner-Hofmann](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greiner%E2%80%93Hormann_clipping_algorithm) algorithm.

I suspect that proper implementation of these methods is rather complex, so recommend to choose ready-to-use library, for example, from [this page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_operations_on_polygons)/software (I don't see Java support claimed except for [this one](https://github.com/helderco/univ-polyclip), but check for possibilities)